# I don't understand C macros

Tags: c, macros

How does the `LOG_FORMAT` expand in `esp_log_write`? What does the `format LOG_RESET_COLOR` do in the `LOG_FORMAT`?

```
 #define LOG_FORMAT(letter, format)  LOG_COLOR_ ## letter #letter " (%d) %s: " format LOG_RESET_COLOR "\n"

 esp_log_write(ESP_LOG_VERBOSE, tag, LOG_FORMAT(V, format), esp_log_timestamp(), tag, ##__VA_ARGS__); }


void esp_log_write(esp_log_level_t level,
                   const char *tag,
                   const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, format);
    vprintf(format, arg);
    va_end(arg);
}
```

Comment: `a ## b` is token concatenation and `# a` is token stringification (both operators are only available in the macro expansion text).

Comment: The `, ##__VA_ARGS__` notation is a GCC extension (also supported by Clang for compatibility with GCC).  It expands to nothing (not even the comma) if there are no variable arguments.

Comment: You will find that there is a macro `LOG_COLOR_V` also defined somewhere.  It probably contains a sequence of characters that change the output colour when used with an ANSI colour terminal.  And `LOG_COLOR_RESET` undoes prior changes of colour back to a default setting of some sort.  It's curious that the `esp_log_write()` function you show takes an argument `tag` that it does not use, too.

Comment: You seem to be using an older version of the ESP logging code (perhaps [v1.0](https://esp-idf.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0/api/log.html)).  More recent code ([ESP API Logging](https://esp-idf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-reference/system/log.html)) has no mention of colours (but the older version has `LOG_COLOR_E`, `…_W`, `…_I`, `…_D`, `…_V` corresponding to logging levels `ERR_LOGE` (error), `ERR_LOGW` (warning), `ERR_LOGI` (info), `ERR_LOGD` (debug), `ERR_LOGV` (verbose).  It may simply be that the colours are now hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In macro expansion `##` means concatenation of any text with a macro argument.
`#` means that the macro argument which follows it will be placed in double quotes.

Now, in 'C' neighboring string literals, separated just by spaces really means a concatenation of 2 strings, i.e. `"hello " "world"` really means `"hello world"`

So, macro `LOG_FORMAT(V, format)` gets expanded to

```
LOG_COLOR_V "V" " (%d) %s: " format LOG_RESET_COLOR "\n"
```

now, the above by itself is not a legal 'C' syntax. So, most likely there are also definitions for `LOG_COLOR_V`,  `format`, and `LOG_RESET_COLOR`. They are supposed to be defined as quoted strings themselves. In this case all the above will be interpreted as a single quoted string.

Comment: Is it ok to have space between LOG_COLOR_ and  ##?